# Objective C - How check if all elements (NSMutableString) of NSMutableArray has a value?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray

I store user's answers inside NSMutableString element of array. i want to show a pop up (call popGoResultsAlert) when all of the array's element has the value and user would complete the questionary , i search over the internet but didn't succeed to find the solution for that.

here is my code :

in first class

```
 [UserData updateUserAnswerValues:[userData objectForKey:@"userAnswerValues"]];
```

//second class  ,part of the userData.m

```
static NSMutableArray *userAnswerValues;

+ (NSMutableArray *)getAnswersCompleted {

    return userAnswerValues;
}

+ (void)updateUserAnswerValues:(NSArray *)newAnswerValues
{
    userAnswerValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [userAnswerValues addObjectsFromArray:newAnswerValues];
}




+ (void)updateUserAnswerValueWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index andValue:(NSMutableString*)value
{
    [userAnswerValues setObject:value atIndexedSubscript:index];
}
```

in 3rd class:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSMutableArray *userAnswerValues = [UserData getAnswersCompleted];

    for (int i=0; i<userAnswerValues.count; i++) {

        id object = userAnswerValues[i];// similar to [myArray objectAtIndex:0]

        if(object && [object length] !=0  && i!=0)
    {
         [self popGoResultsAlert];
        break;

    } else if (!object) {
        continue;
    }

    }

}
```

Edit : 
//4th class , here seems the origin data is populated to the userAnswerValues base on what user pick from PickerView , that index has the value and that value is put by selectedOptionValue variable ... I have debug the userAnswerValues and notice the value has 56 elements like userAnswerValues = ( "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 4, 3, 4, 3, "", ... (fill the rest with ,"" until 56 items> , "" );
so whenever a user select a value in PickerView one of the above element filled out with index number , so my question is how search through these mutable array and see if all item has value...

```
   NSUInteger index = [self.currentQuestion.index integerValue];
    [UserData updateUserAnswerWithIndex:index andValue:self.selectedOptionIndex];
    Option *selectedOption = [self.currentOptions objectAtIndex:[self.selectedOptionIndex integerValue]];
    NSString *selectedOptionValue = selectedOption.value;
    [UserData updateUserAnswerValueWithIndex:index andValue:selectedOptionValue];
```

there is 3 section of questionary that store all the answer's value in a single and same array. with above code , the alert pop up whenever each of 3 section would be completed , my intend is it would only show pop up when all 3 section is completed....

I have test `[object length] !=0 , ![object isEqual:[NSNull null]] ,      ![object isEqualToString:@""]` with no luck , all of the 3 has same behaviour (show pop up after each section is completed ,

These project has not written by me from the scratch so i am trying to debug and fix some of it's bugs , when i debug userAnswerValues , i see that the items of NSMutableArray had different type in different elements type, as you see item 32th is _NSFConstantString with empty value , while the item 33th is NSTagedPointerString... please see the attached file for more details.

[image: Debug snapshots]

Comment: Use a bool value or check if i == lastObject  [you know this is the end of array] and then put show alert.

Comment: FYI - `object` can't be `nil`. No need to check to see if it is.

Comment: @user3344236 as far as i know , the items of array are not filled out in the order , because there is 3 sections of questionary , that the value of all those 3 sections store in a same array , so user might choose 3rd section first to answer , so last object might completed , but first and second section is empty , so in this case i don't want to show the pop up , only when all items of array has a value ...

Comment: @user3344236  , can you please show me in the source code how can i solve it with a bool value?

Comment: The reason you see different types is that NSString is a class cluster. The objects it instantiates are various optimized concrete subclasses that should only be considered NSString or CFString. They meet the requirements to be those.

Comment: Edit your question to show how `userAnswerValues` is created and initialised. This is crucial information for anybody trying to help you, not only cannot a `nil` by stored in an array as @rmaddy points out, you cannot store an item at index *n* of an array unless all indexes less than *n* have a value.

Comment: @CRD , I have edited OP and i add more lines of code to clarify how userAnswerValues is created. Please let me know if anything else needed? Thanks

Comment: Good, but the initial values stored in the array are still missing. I.e. What are the values in the object returned by `[userData objectForKey:@"userAnswerValues"]]`? Without knowing these values nobody can help you with how to test your condition.

Comment: But what's the origin of the data?  Saying that it's loaded from `[userData objectForKey:@"userAnswerValues"]` just leads to the question of what was put there.  Somewhere something must be populated with real data, not just passed references to other arrays.

Comment: @CRD , I don't know exactly what you mean is missing , i show NSMutableArray how is created and instantiated and how the value is set with the code... i debug over the line you referred in your last comment, and i see in console `userAnswerValues =     (
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        "",
        4,
        3,
        4,
        3,
        "", 
         ... , ""
    );`
so the initial values are either empty string of "" or string of index numbers ...

Comment: @PhillipMills Thanks for your reply , i would try to edit the OP and find how original developer. add origin Data ... i would edited the OP and share more codes in a minutes. Thanks

Comment: I have edited my original post , please see the 4nd part of class , and edit note in OP

Comment: Your last comment is a good enough answer.  It verifies that your test should be looking for empty strings (not nils).

Answer (score 0):

What I think you need is very similar to the previous answer.  Here, I'll translate to your data names.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    BOOL showPopup = YES;    // Assume success
    NSMutableArray *userAnswerValues = [UserData getAnswersCompleted];

    // Try to go all the way through the array without finding an empty string
    for (int i = 0; i < userAnswerValues.count; i++) {
        id object = userAnswerValues[i];
        if ([object length] == 0) {
            showPopup = NO;  // Something is not filled in
            break;
        }
    }
    if (showPopup) {
        [self popGoResultsAlert];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Bool nilBool = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < yourArray.count; i ++)
{
      NSString *value = [yourArray ObjectAtIndex:i];

      if([value isEqual: @""] || value == nil)
      {
          nilBool = 1;
      }
}

if(nilBool)
{
     //one if your values is nil!
}
else
{
    //all values are filled, you are good to go
}
```

Comment: what is that supposed to be? it is not even answer to OP at all.

Comment: Bashir, I have tried your code , in line NSString *value = [yourArray ObjectAtIndex:i]; , when i replace my NSMutableArray i got a compile error with your code , that says : No Visible @interface for 'NsMutableArray' declares the selector objectAtIndex

Comment: i wrote this without xcode, the syntax is like this [yourArray objectAtIndex:0];